# How to deal with broken multipart uploads?

Tags: php, apache, upload, multipart

I have a PHP script that receives images from remote devices and saves them to the database. The script, launched from Apache, receives first a header defining what is being uploaded, and then the contents of the images uploaded, all as a single multipart transmission. After successfully adding the images, it replies with a confirmation for the device.

Now the problem is the connection isn't very reliable. Sometimes the transmission times out. That wouldn't be a problem as the device resends the data after some time if it didn't receive the confirmation. Except if the transmission is broken halfway through, Apache launches the script as usual, and the script happily saves the incomplete set of images to the database, with their creation timestamps as unique keys. Then the remote device resends data, which then the script receives correctly, but it's unable to save it as the unique key is already taken by the corrupt data.

Is there some reliable way to either tell from within a PHP script that it's been launched on incomplete multipart transmission, or prevent Apache from starting it if the transmission didn't end successfully?

(we can't really change the database structure or the format received from the remote device.)

Comment: `Except if the transmission is broken halfway through, Apache launches the script as usual`  that sounds weird. Do you have any log data for these cases? Can you log the `$_FILES` array for a while and check what the `error` variable is set to when the upload is incomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your device's application code for send timeout. Maybe connection is too slow and it brakes it as time limit is reached. In that case apache server would run php script with partially received data in spite of not matching Content-Length header.

Comment: It appears to be the case - the client would send FIN on timeout when the transmission took too long. Now it would be nice if I could get Apache to refuse data that doesn't match Content-Length.